# how to gain access to local files from IAP Desktop Session

Tags: google-compute-engine

I just changed from Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) to IAP Desktop in connecting to the VM. I realised that I could not access my local drive from the IAP Session as it is in the RDC.I need any information that could assist me in accessing my local drive from the IAP Desktop Session. Thanks all

Comment: Please clarify about the local drive, is it in VM or your local machine? Please note that IAP's TCP forwarding feature lets you control who can access administrative services like SSH and RDP on your backends from the public internet, it does not affect the hardware driver.

Comment: Thanks Milad,I mean my local machine.

Comment: I used to access it when I was using  the Remote Desktop Connection. I want this access to enable me send files between the 2 machines. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't send files via IAP Desktop.

You can start a tunnel to the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy via [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/start-iap-tunnel) in Cloud SDK:

$ gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel [instance-name] 3389 \
      --local-host-port=localhost:[port] \
      --zone=[zone]

And then start a RDP session using the Remote Desktop Connection in Windows with

Computer: localhost:[port] and [password which generate in the Cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-passwords-for-windows-instances).

I recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDsZEKUXsU0) for your consideration.